# require('bignumber.js') fails in truffle test, npm ls -g shows it's installed (Windows)

Tags: javascript, npm, solidity, truffle, bignumber.js

I'm trying to test solidity code with truffle. As the number values returned from (or sent to) contracts are `BigNumber`s I want to require the library. My current test is a one-liner:

```
let BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
```

called *hello_test.js*.

If I run `npm ls -g | grep bignumber` I can see `+-- bignumber.js@7.2.1`, so it's installed; but if I try:

```
truffle.cmd test .\test\hello_test.js
```

I get

> Error: Cannot find module 'bignumber.js'

What's going on?

Truffle version 4.0.6, npm version 5.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way node require works:
`require('xx')` will search for

```
./node_modules/xx.js
./node_modules/xx/index.js
./node_modules/xx/package.json
```

If it can not find, it will go ahead to search by the environmental variable, `NODE_PATH`. If that is not specified, it won't search any global module.

So you can check your `NODE_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why, but installing the `bignumber.js` package locally did the trick:

```
C:\project\> npm install bignumber.js
+ bignumber.js@7.2.1
added 1 package and moved 1 package in 4.222s

C:\project\> truffle.cmd test .\test\hello_test.js

  0 passing (2 ms)
```

The `bignumber.js` package now appears in both `npm ls -g` and `npm ls` (when run from the project root dir).